# pandas dataframe venn diagram

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes, and for one exercise I had to join them together and get the common rows based on country column

[image]

However for this new exercise I have to get the length of everything outside the join (the middle)

I have this code:

```
  ScimEn = pd.read_excel('assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    ScimEn.set_index('Country')
    print(ScimEn)
  
    #ScimEn = ScimEn.sort_values(by=['Rank']).head(15)

    merged_df = pd.merge(Energy, GDP, on="Country")
    merged_df2 = pd.merge(merged_df, ScimEn, on="Country")
    merged_df2.set_index('Country')
```

How do I get all the count of rows that didnt match the inner join?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the number of rows, then you can try doing an outer join like so

```
merged_df = pd.merge(Energy, GDP, on="Country", how='outer')
```

Do the outer join just the same as you did for your inner join, and then obtain the difference between the outer join and the inner join. There would be the number of rows that don't match the inner join